# Insufficient system memory in resource pool SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jboss, fuseesb

I have long running queries which I can not avoid, Now when I run them for the first time, it runs successfully but next time when I run the same application sql server error log gives me an error saying  "There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query. "

How can I resolve it , please help me out to come out of this nasty problem.
This error comes, while loading hibernate entity files in my case.

Here is error log of DB.

```
Grants                                            0
Waiting                                           0
Available                                       660
Current Max                                     660
Future Max                                      660
Physical Max                                   4095
Next Request                                      0
Waiting For                                       0
Cost                                              0
Timeout                                           0
Wait Time                                         0
2014-01-17 17:00:43.81 spid87      
Small Query Memory Objects (internal)         Value
---------------------------------------- ----------
Grants                                            0
Waiting                                           0
Available                                         0
Current Max                                       0
Future Max                                        0
2014-01-17 17:00:43.81 spid87      
Optimization Queue (internal)                 Value
---------------------------------------- ----------
Overall Memory                             35807232
Target Memory                              20291584
Last Notification                                 0
Timeout                                           6
Early Termination Factor                          5
2014-01-17 17:00:43.81 spid87      
Small Gateway (internal)                      Value
---------------------------------------- ----------
Configured Units                                 16
Available Units                                  15
Acquires                                          1
Waiters                                           0
Threshold Factor                             380000
Threshold                                    380000
2014-01-17 17:00:43.81 spid87      
Medium Gateway (internal)                     Value
---------------------------------------- ----------
Configured Units                                  4
Available Units                                   3
Acquires                                          1
Waiters                                           0
Threshold Factor                                 12
Threshold                                   1690965
2014-01-17 17:00:43.81 spid87      
Big Gateway (internal)                        Value
---------------------------------------- ----------
Configured Units                                  1
Available Units                                   0
Acquires                                          1
Waiters                                           0
Threshold Factor                                  8
Threshold                                   2536448
2014-01-17 17:00:43.81 spid87      
Memory Pool Manager                           Pages
---------------------------------------- ----------
Reserved Current                                  0
Reserved Limit                                 1597
2014-01-17 17:00:43.81 spid87      
Memory Pool (internal)                        Pages
---------------------------------------- ----------
Allocations                                    3584
Predicted                                      6199
Private Target                                    0
Private Limit                                     0
Total Target                                   5181
Total Limit                                    5181
OOM Count                                         1
2014-01-17 17:00:43.82 spid87      
MEMORYBROKER_FOR_CACHE (internal)             Pages
---------------------------------------- ----------
Allocations                                    1643
Rate                                          -3058
Target Allocations                             1152
Future Allocations                                0
Overall                                        4371
Last Notification                                 2
2014-01-17 17:00:43.82 spid87      
MEMORYBROKER_FOR_STEAL (internal)             Pages
---------------------------------------- ----------
Allocations                                    1941
Rate                                           1592
Target Allocations                             2477
Future Allocations                                0
Overall                                        4371
Last Notification                                 0
2014-01-17 17:00:43.82 spid87      
MEMORYBROKER_FOR_RESERVE (internal)           Pages
---------------------------------------- ----------
Allocations                                       0
Rate                                              0
Target Allocations                              717
Future Allocations                             1023
Overall                                        4371
Last Notification                                 0
2014-01-17 17:00:43.87 spid87      Error: 701, Severity: 17, State: 123.
2014-01-17 17:00:43.87 spid87      There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the StackOverflow "reputation" to add a comment, so I'll have to add this here.

I've stumbled upon this Microsoft KB article:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982854.

It states that there is a fix in Cumulative Update 1 to SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 that addresses this issue.  Unfortunately, I have not been able to fully test this during our downtime yet, but it directly references the same issue I'm having which results in the same error message you're seeing.

What is the version number of SQL Server 2008 R2 that you're using?  I'm on 10.50.1600 (original, gold, no service packs), and I'm receiving this error.